# Type erasure of generic types, better alternative to dynamic

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I am trying to create a worker pool that can take as input any `Func<T>` or `Action`, return a Task and schedule the result of that task in some thread at some future time.

I am aware I can use `ThreadPool` or `Task.Factory` but I am doing this for the sake of learning.

Now my implementation below relies on me being able to queue `TaskCompletionSource<T>` by wrapping it around in `dynamic` inside `TaskWrapper`. I don't feel comfortable doing this (as I can imagine this has a non-negligible runtime cost) but I don't know of any alternatives.

```
public class WorkerHub
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<TaskWrapper> _tasks;
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public WorkerHub()
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<TaskWrapper>();
    }

    public Task<TResult> Post<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
    {
        var cts = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        var wrapper = new TaskWrapper {CompletionSource = cts, Function = func};
        _tasks.Enqueue(wrapper);
        return cts.Task;
    }

    public Task Post(Action action)
    {
        var cts = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        var wrapper = new TaskWrapper {CompletionSource = cts, Function = action, isVoid = true};
        _tasks.Enqueue(wrapper);
        return cts.Task;
    }

    private TaskWrapper Pop()
    {
        _tasks.TryDequeue(out var wrapper);
        return wrapper;
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;

        _timer.Interval = 2500;
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var wrapper = Pop();
            if (wrapper != null) wrapper.CompletionSource.SetResult(wrapper.isVoid ? true : wrapper.Function());
        };
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
    }

    private class TaskWrapper
    {
        public bool isVoid { get; set; }
        public dynamic Function { get; set; }
        public dynamic CompletionSource { get; set; }
    }
```

What is the "proper" way of being able to bind to the different types of completion sources and the different types of input functions in the same collection?

Comment: The common base type of Func<T> and Action is Delegate, or you can get full type erasure Java-style by making it Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach that does not involve holding on to the delegate or task completion source is via lambda expressions

```
public class WorkerHub {
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<TaskWrapper> _tasks;
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public WorkerHub() {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<TaskWrapper>();
    }

    public Task<TResult> Post<TResult>(Func<TResult> func) {
        var cts = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();

        Action handler = () => {
            cts.SetResult(func());
        };

        var wrapper = new TaskWrapper { Invoke = handler };
        _tasks.Enqueue(wrapper);
        return cts.Task;
    }

    public Task Post(Action action) {
        var cts = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        Action handler = () => {
            action();
            cts.SetResult(true);
        };
        var wrapper = new TaskWrapper { Invoke = handler };
        _tasks.Enqueue(wrapper);
        return cts.Task;
    }

    private TaskWrapper Pop()
    {
        _tasks.TryDequeue(out var wrapper);
        return wrapper;
    }


    public void Start() {
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;

        _timer.Interval = 2500;
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => {
            var wrapper = Pop();
            if (wrapper != null)
                wrapper.Invoke();
        };
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop() {
    }

    private class TaskWrapper {
        public Action Invoke { get; set; }
    }
}
```

an `Action` delegate is created to handle the desired behavior and that is given to the wrapper to be invoked when needed.

The wrapper now becomes redundant and can be removed altogether

```
public class WorkerHub {
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _tasks;
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public WorkerHub() {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
    }

    public Task<TResult> Post<TResult>(Func<TResult> func) {
        var cts = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        Action handler = () => {
            cts.SetResult(func());
        };
        _tasks.Enqueue(handler);
        return cts.Task;
    }

    public Task Post(Action action) {
        var cts = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        Action handler = () => {
            action();
            cts.SetResult(true);
        };
        _tasks.Enqueue(handler);
        return cts.Task;
    }

    public void Start() {
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;

        _timer.Interval = 2500;
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => {
            Action handler = null;
            if (_tasks.TryDequeue(out  handler) && handler != null)
                handler.Invoke();
        };
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop() {
    }
}
```

Yes, there are more refactors that can be done to improve this design, but this should be enough to get the general idea across

Comment: Ah lambdas! Yes this is familiar ground, and much better solution.

Comment: This is like type erase with std::function wrapping lambdas in C++ world, thanks for this! Yes I do have a lot to fix here, for starters that timer is going away. Any other issues you see that are glaringly obvious (not to me).

Answer (score 2):

I think moving some functionality *into* `TaskWrapper` and defining a generic implementation that derives from it makes a lot of sense:

```
private class TaskWrapper
{
    private readonly Action _function;
    private readeonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> _cts;
    public TaskWrapper (Action function, TaskCompletionSource<bool> cts) {
       _function = function;
       _cts = cts;
    }
    protected TaskWrapper () {
       _function = null;
       _cts = null;
    }
    public virtual void DoWork() {
       _function();
       cts.SetResult(true);
    }
}
private class TaskWrapper<T> : TaskWrapper {
    private readonly Func<T> _function;
    private readeonly TaskCompletionSource<T> _cts;
    public TaskWrapper (Func<T> function, TaskCompletionSource<T> cts) : base() {
       _function = function;
       _cts = cts;
    }
    public override void DoWork(){
       _cts.SetResult(_function());
    }
}
```

And now your dispatcher can just call `DoWork` without knowing whether the generic was the one used during construction.

---

I'd also note that your current implementation should make you feel more than uncomfortable. It fails to *call* `Function` for the `Action` items.

Comment: Woops :D I was being a bit hasty there, this is also a good alternative.

Comment: @arynaq - yes, I think I prefer [Nkosi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52647923/15498) but I'll leave it here as a viable alternative and it may help steer someone with a similar problem not so easily solved using lambdas.